# How to make each ion-slide to adopt it's height based on the data it holds?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have used a `*ngFor` which loop throw an array and populate 7 slides with data. The problem that I'm facing is that if 1 slide has more data all other slides adopts the height of that slide, this makes other slides to have a large blank space between where it's data ends and the bottom of the slide. How do I fix this?

Below is my ion-slides code:

**.html file**

```
            <ion-item *ngFor="let b of default">
                <h2>
                <b>{{b.name}} {{b.surname}}</b> ({{b.No}})
                </h2>
            </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

default is an object which populate the 7 slides.

the default is in the .ts file

Comment: You can add custom class on your items like:
`[ngClass]="{'headColor': accountTab == true, 'myhead': accountTab !== true }"`

Comment: @Najamussaqib thanks i have been doing some research on the custom class but i can't find good examples. can you please provide links if available.

Comment: Can you share your data so i can make example on it. what type of Data you want to show...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<ion-slides>` is built using Swiper (see docs [here](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#layout)) which allows for adding configuration options to the slides. In your case, you will want to add in `autoHeight: true` like so:

**html**

```
<ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideConfig">
  <ion-slide>
    // slide content here
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

**ts**

```
slideConfig = {
    effect: 'flip',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centeredSlides: true,
    autoHeight: true
  };
```

Checkout the docs linked above for more options. Good luck!